# VBA statements for pagesetup only executed in debug mode

Tags: excel, vba, debug-mode, step-into, page-setup

The following sub is supposed to prepare pagesetup for a PDF output.
For instance, if due to other attached printers the pagebrakes are messed up, the sub should fix it back to 1 page wide and 3 pages tall.

```
Sub adjustPB(ws As Variant, ps As XlPaperSize)
'On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ws.PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    '.Orientation = xlPortrait
    .PaperSize = ps
    .Zoom = 100
    .Zoom = False
    Debug.Print .Zoom
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    Debug.Print .Zoom
    Debug.Print .FitToPagesWide
    .FitToPagesTall = 3
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

The sub actually works as expected in single step (F8), when I add a breakpoint at 'With ws.PateSetup'.
If I run it using F5, however, it ignores the statements.
The debug prints show, that the values for the properties didn't change.

Things tried so far:
add delays before .zoom and .FitPagesWide with DoEvents for up to 1 sec. No change. Zoom for instance remains 55. 
In singlestep, Zoom reads FALSE in the end.
Any explanations / hints what's going wrong here?

Comment: what values you get in Debug Window?

Comment: If I run it with F5, zoom values remain as shown in page setup dialogue.
If I run Singlestep, zoom shows FALSE and the pages are adjusted properly. Pagesetup shows greyed out zoom level required to fit to 1 page wide (here 52).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.PrintCommunication` may be the key. The documentation is rather obscure at this point but it looks like Excel caches all commands when `.PrintCommunication` is OFF and dumps them to page setup engine when you turn `.PrintCommunication` ON. That may be the reason for not seeing any changes when running with F5. (The services of the debugger are even more obscure for me.)

Try applying

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
     ' .... 
    .Parent.Application.PrintCommunication = True
    .Zoom = 100
    .Zoom = False
    Debug.Print .Zoom
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    Debug.Print .Zoom
    Debug.Print .FitToPagesWide
   .FitToPagesTall = 3
   .Parent.Application.PrintCommunication = False
   ' .... 
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

I'am also curious to see the result :)

Comment: Interresting, this solved it.
In the meantime I also got it running with printcommunication=false, if I use xlPaperA4 instead of xlPaperEsheet. 
Thanks for the solution, but I guess MS should definitely look into this since it doesn't look really logic to me, what's going on there.